# Electron in its orbital

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I was just wondering online about as in how does an atom actually look like and I stumbled upon a page that discussed the matter. However, the statement

> We sometimes say the orbital describes the probability of finding the electron at a certain spot. If you're thinking of the electron wandering around like Waldo and hanging around some places more than others, that's false. If you force the issue and require an electron to behave as a particle, true. For example, if you fire a beam of photons at an atom and see how they scatter off electrons, the photons will scatter as if you had more electrons in some places than others, but that's not what literally happens down at the subatomic level. [Source](https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/Petrology/WhatAtomsLookLike.HTM)

was totally in disagreement with what I have been taught in the university lectures. I have always been taught that the position of an electron can be expressed as the probability of finding it in a finite space called an orbital. Could anyone explain what the author meant in the quote above from his essay.

Answer (score 0):

The author is purely stating that the wavefunction doesn't describe an electron with a well-defined position to nature, that just wanders around and we don't know where it is, but rather that it is intrinsically not-localised to any single point in space but rather a distribution over a range of eigenvalues. Essentially saying "this fuzziness isn't an artifact of our lack of knowledge about where the electron likes to spend it's time moving between, but that the electron is actually spread out over that volume".

Comment: Thank you for your response and forgive my ignorance on the matter but can you explain how the electron is spread out over the volume?. I mean I think the fact that my intuition drives me to think electron as a particle preventing me from grasping the point. I would much appreciate if you can try to enlighten me further as to how I can at least imagine the electron spreading over the volume.